# Как убрать подчеркивание?

Tags: html, css

Добрый день! Я дико извиняюсь за следующий глупый вопрос, но факт остается фактом, впервые за много лет работы со стилем к моему большому стыду не могу справиться вот с чем: как у `span` убрать подчеркивание, в том числе и при наведении как на картинку, так и на сам `span`? При чем у `a` подчеркивание есть и должно быть, т.е. на странице ссылки при наведении подчеркиваются, и при этом мне нужно исключить подчеркивание именно у `<span class="help">`. Каким только способом не пытался, хоть тресни - подчеркивает. Никогда бы не подумал, что приду сюда с таким вопросом. Подскажите, пожалуйста.

```css
span.help,
a span.help,
a:hover span.help {
 text-decoration: none;
}
```

```html
<p>
<a href="#"><img src="kartinka.jpg">
<span class="help">Мемориальный комплекс</span>
</a>
</p>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Это происходит, потому что подчеркивание применяется именно к `a`, а не `span`, и манипулируя стилями `span`, вы не сможете повлиять на стили `a`. Поэтому единственный выход - ввести новый класс, например, help-a:

```css
a {
  text-decoration: none
}

a:hover {
  text-decoration: underline;
}

a.help-a:hover {
  text-decoration: none;
}
```

```html
<p>
  <a class="help-a" href="#"><img src="kartinka.jpg">
    <span class="help">Мемориальный комплекс</span>
  </a>
</p>
```

Comment: @LADYX обновил ответ